# Spring boot PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer with @ProperySource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple question about `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and `@PropertySource` annotation. I have simple class with bean. I would like to inject property from `application.properties` and some another `test.properties` wiht `@Value` annotation. I read in several sources that `@PropertySource` needs to define static`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean. From documentation:

> In order to resolve ${...} placeholders in  definitions or
>   @Value annotations using properties from a PropertySource, one must
>   register a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. This happens
>   automatically when using  in XML, but
>   must be explicitly registered using a static @Bean method when using
>   @Configuration classes.

But for me it works fine without this bean. Is Spring in some way auto configures `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` at application startup? Here is my simple example (first property is from `application.properties` and second from `test.properties`):

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Value("${first.property}")
    private String firstProp;

    @Value("${second.property}")
    private String secondProp;

    @Bean
    public TestModel getModel() {
        TestModel model = new TestModel();
        model.setFirstProperty(firstProp);
        model.setSecondProperty(secondProp);
        return model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The static `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean is registered automatically when missing by `PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration` class which appears to be introduced in Spring Boot [1.5.0.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.html) (as there is no on-line javadoc for it in the previous releases).

Interestingly this new auto configuration is not mentioned in [Spring Boot 1.5 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes).